# Errors when Using Status Bar Notification Code from Android Developers Site

Tags: android

I found the following code on developers.android.com, but AIDE is marking certain things wrong. What should I do to fix these errors?

The TaskStackBuilder entities say ambigous imported type (2 of these)

Unknown type of variable for StackBuilder (3 of these)

Unknown entity StackBuilder (3 of these)

```
NotificationCompat.Builder myBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this) 
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher) 
    .setContentTitle("My notification") 
    .setContentText("Hello World!"); 

Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this); 
stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class); 
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent); 

PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent( 0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT ); 
myBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent); 

NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 
mNotificationManager.notify(mId, myBuilder.build());
```

Comment: As a beginner Android developer, try using Eclipse or Android Studio, which will help you by suggesting corrections for problems like this.

Comment: Use this dependencies // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.core/core
compile group: 'androidx.core', name: 'core', version: '1.0.0-alpha1'